# Undecidable Problem for Regular Languages

Tags: computability, regular-languages, undecidability

It might seems weird, but, Are there any **undecidable** problems concerning regular languages? I mean questions concerning the regular languages, not the problems like "Is the language of a TM regular?".

Clarification: By the questions regarding regular languages, I mean that the problem consists of regular languages, i.e. the relation between two or more regular languages, and/or about the properties of a regular language.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your statement "*problems concerning regular languages*" is not well-defined. The statement *not the problems like "Is the language of a TM regular*" does not help either.

Comment: @fade2black Agreed, but not every question can be perfectly well-defined. I think this one's OK, even though there is scope for disagreement about whether any given answer really is valid.

Comment: Would PCP or transducer equivalence count?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there are undecidable problems like the Post Correspondence Problem that can be coded into the language of a finite state automaton, as explained in my earlier answer to a (slightly broader) question: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/6198

The result can be traced to a paper by Engelfriet and Rozenberg dealing with the so called twin shuffle operation.
*Fixed Point Languages, Equality Languages, and Representation of
Recursively Enumerable Languages* (J. ACM)
[doi:10.1145/322203.322211](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/322203.322211)

Recently Endrullis, Shallit and Smith presented the paper *Undecidability and Finite Automata* at the conference DLT2017 ([doi:10.1007/978-3-319-62809-7_11](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-62809-7_11), [arxiv:1702.01394](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.01394)) which deals with your question:

> **Abstract.** Using a novel rewriting problem, we show that several natural decision
>   problems about finite automata are undecidable (i.e., recursively
>   unsolvable). In contrast, we also prove three related problems are
>   decidable. We apply one result to prove the undecidability of a
>   related problem about k-automatic sets of rational numbers.

I am very proud that one of the references in this paper is to my earlier SE answer!

Answer (score 2):

This answer might not be entirely to your taste because it uses Turing machines. I think it's a valid answer, since the input to the problem is a regular language, rather than a Turing machine.

Fix a universal Turing machine $U$ and consider the problem "Does $U(x)$ halt for every $x\in L$?" (or for some $x\in L$).  For concreteness, we can represent $L$ itself by giving an encoding of a DFA that decides it.

It's easy to see that this language is undecidable: we can reduce the halting problem to it by translating the question "Does $M(w)$ halt?" into "Does $U(x)$ halt for every $x\in L$?", where $L = \{\langle M;w\rangle\}$.  It's easy to translate a description of $M$ and $w$ into a description of a DFA that accepts only the string $\langle M;w\rangle$.

Comment: I was also thinking of $\{\langle M \rangle \mid L(M) \in \mathrm{REG} \}$ for several classes of machines $M$, but those are more about those machines than regular languages, aren't they?

Comment: @Raphael Yeah, that's basically the problem forbidden in the question.